# Use of undeclared identifier 'ENOMEM'

Tags: c, xcode, libarchive

i using "libarchive" for my xcode project but get bellow errors

```
if (bytes_read < mine->block_size && ferror(mine->f)) {
    archive_set_error(a, errno, "Error reading file");
}
```

Use of undeclared identifier 'errno'

```
if (mine == NULL || b == NULL) {
    archive_set_error(a, ENOMEM, "No memory");
    free(mine);
    free(b);
    return (ARCHIVE_FATAL);
}
```

Use of undeclared identifier 'ENOMEM'

```
if (format_number(archive_entry_uid(entry), h + USTAR_uid_offset, USTAR_uid_size, USTAR_uid_max_size, strict)) {
    archive_set_error(&a->archive, ERANGE, "Numeric user ID too large");
    ret = ARCHIVE_FAILED;
}
```

Use of undeclared identifier 'ERANGE'

```
   write_nulls(struct archive_write *a, size_t padding)
{
  int ret;
  size_t to_write;

   while (padding > 0) {
    to_write = padding < a->null_length ? padding : a->null_length;
    ret = (a->compressor.write)(a, a->nulls, to_write);
    if (ret != ARCHIVE_OK)
    return (ret);
    padding -= to_write;
}
return (ARCHIVE_OK);}
```

No member named 'compressor' in 'struct archive_write'

how i can fix this errors?

[image: screenshot of error]

https://github.com/Tarsnap/tarsnap/blob/master/libarchive/archive_write_set_format_ustar.c

Comment: Ideally post a code snippet instead of a picture of code.

Comment: Have you included errno? `#include <errno.h>`

Comment: `ENOMEM` is not a C standard error code, yet quite common.  OTOH, `ERANGE` is C standard and defined in `<errno.h>`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ENONEM` and `ERANGE` are macros that are defined in `errno.h`. As for `errno`, it is an integer variable set when some errors are occurred.

Thus, to access those variables/defines you need to add `#include <errno.h>` in your file.

For more documentation : [man errno](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html)